# javascript preventDefault() being ignored

Tags: javascript, django, preventdefault, django-autocomplete-light

so I have tried to find a solution to my issue, but it seems unique to the other preventDefault() questions I have seen on SO and Google. It also may be a bit too narrow, but if anyone has any debugging tips, those would be appreciated, too.

I have a site that shows different video "bookmarks" to users who can click on them and change the video / seekTo time playing in a div on the page. There are 3 places a user can do this. On the left is a menu showing the "top 10 most recently viewed videos", on the right is a D3.js based topology tree, and at the top there is a search box built off of django-autocomplete-light. All three methods use the same javascript function (playvid) to change the video and update metadata information on the webpage. For example, a user clicks a link and is taken go minute 4 of Video 1, then clicks another link and is taken to minute 9 of Video 45.

When I implemented this on my development machine, all three methods worked with FF 18 and Safari 6 (Django 1.4.3, Python 2.7.3, running Django's web server). Then I put it onto a production server (Django 1.4.3, Python 2.6.6, Apache / mod_wsgi). Now the method with django-autocomplete-light's search box doesn't work, but the other two, do! I assume the different Python versions shouldn't be the culprit...? The autocomplete code was the same as my development code, but now it seems like some sort of javascript problem with preventDefault()? After hours of debugging though, I cannot figure out where and why, since the code seems to just ignore my e.preventDefault(); call...here is my /navigation_autocomplete/script.html code that captures what a user clicks within the autocomplete search box (although I feel like the issue is javascript, not specifically this Django module):

```
{% load url from future %}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#navigation_autocomplete').yourlabsAutocomplete({
        url: '{% url 'navigation_autocomplete' %}',
        choiceSelector: 'a',
    }).input.bind('selectChoice', function(e, choice, autocomplete) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var URL = choice.attr('href');
        alert('this should not follow the link!!');
        playvid(URL);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

The alert() pops up in FF and Safari, and using Firebug, I can see that the browser tries to load playvid() but then follows the link--e.preventDefault(); is completely ignored. As you can see, I tried to stop the bubbling, too (getting desparate), but no luck.

Does anyone have any ideas on why my preventDefault() code might be ignored in this one specific method, but it works fine in my other calls (especially when it worked fine in development for all 3 methods)? Or debugging tips on how to track this down?

Thanks!

===========

## Update

I tried jpic's solution, but it doesn't work...here is the new block of code (maybe I fat fingered something...):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#navigation_autocomplete a').on('click', function(e) {e.preventDefault(); });
    $('#navigation_autocomplete').yourlabsAutocomplete({
        url: '/video_search/navigation/',
        choiceSelector: 'a',
    }).input.bind('selectChoice', function(e, choice, autocomplete) {
        var URL = choice.attr('href');
        alert('this should not follow the link!!');
        playvid(URL);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The event is a click. is that right?

Comment: Yes, sorry, to clarify the event is a click--although in the autocomplete code they have bound it to a custom trigger, "selectChoice", which is defined as a click within the search box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A fuzzy implementation

Your code prevents default **for selectChoice**, but not for click !

Autocomplete objects trigger selectChoice on the `input` element when a choice is selected either via mouse or keyboard. It does not mess with the `click` event. If you don't want browser default `click` event, then why use `<a>` ?

### Alternative implementation suggestion

You could make an autocomplete template like this:

```
{% for video in video_qs %}
<span class="div choice" data-href="{{ video.get_absolute_url }}">{{ video }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

With such js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#navigation_autocomplete')
        .yourlabsAutocomplete({
            url: '{% url 'navigation_autocomplete' %}',
            choiceSelector: '.choice',
        }).input.bind('selectChoice', function(e, choice, autocomplete) {
            playvid(choice.data('href'));
        });
});
</script>
```

This simplicity by design is my favorite feature in django-autocomplete-light.

### Fixing the fuzzy implementation anyway

If you really need unclickable `<a>` tags, then you could use jQuery `on()`, ie:

```
$('#navigation_autocomplete').on('click', 'a', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#navigation_autocomplete')
        .on('click', 'a', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); })
        .yourlabsAutocomplete({
            url: '{% url 'navigation_autocomplete' %}',
            choiceSelector: 'a',
        }).input.bind('selectChoice', function(e, choice, autocomplete) {
            var URL = choice.attr('href');
            playvid(URL);
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi jpic, I just added that line and still get the same behavior on FF and Safari. In Firebug and the Safari developer's console, the line that you show is in the source code. But when I click on a result in the search box, the following happens: 1) alert window pops up, I click it, 2) JS console shows call to playvid, 3) page redirects to anchor's original href--preventDefault is still ignored?

Comment: My bad, this was due to a wrong usage of jquery `on()`. Answer updated, could you try it ? Thanks !

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Any ideas why the .on functionality did not work for me (need to chain the binds instead of separate assignments?), or why it worked fine on my development machine but not my production machine? PS--for anyone who wants to implement, you need to use the right </span> bracket in jpic's Alternative Implementation Solution.

Comment: I told you, the first code i posted was a wrong usage of `on()`. This `$('#navigation_autocomplete a').on('click', function(e)` is wrong and should be `$('#navigation_autocomplete').on('click', 'a', function(e)` to really emulate the deprecated `live()`. Thanks for your feedback !